# Background Task gets cancelled by OS with BackgroundTaskCancellationReason as executiontimeexceeded

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, background-task

I have a UWP application where I have added background task support for doing certain things while my application is in background. I am doing exactly as it is mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

I have one separate project for Background Tasks and in my package manifest file I have declared that my app uses background tasks (but "timer" task since I am using TimerTrigger). Code:

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder backgroundTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder { Name = "NotificationUpdater", TaskEntryPoint = "NamespaceOfMyBackgroundTaskInterfaceImplementation.BackgroundTask"};

backgroundTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));

BackgroundTaskRegistration backgroundTaskRegistration = backgroundTaskBuilder.Register();
```

Code inside BackgroundTask class:

```
namespace NamespaceOfMyBackgroundTaskInterfaceImplementation
{
    public sealed class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            //Code to run in the background

            taskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskInstanceCanceled;
        }

        private void OnTaskInstanceCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {
            _logger.LogInfo("Background Agent: The Operating System requested cancellation. Reason: {0}.", reason);
        }
    }
}
```

When I close my application, after 20-25 minutes the background task gets triggered but when it starts executing the `Run()` method, OS cancels the execution with `BackgroundTaskCancellationReason` as `executiontimeexceeded`. Sometimes the cancellation happens right after the background task starts executing.

Note: When I use lifecycle events dropdown in VS to trigger the background task, the OS never cancels the execution and it keeps running without any issues.

Edit: I added some logging to know the timings and here is what I found:

```
BG Task started at 5/4/2016 5:58:25 PM
BG Task Cancelled at 5/4/2016 5:58:50 PM
```

So it's not even waiting for 30 seconds (which is supposed to be the time limit for the background task execution) and it terminates it in approximately 25 seconds (in some cases this time difference was as low as 20 seconds).

Comment: Do you use GetDeferral method of taskInstance? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.ibackgroundtaskinstance.getdeferral

Comment: What sort of stuff does your `Run` method actually do? Are you missing an `await` at all?

Comment: @RavingDev Yes, I am using GetDeferral and also calling Comlete() on it once I am done awaiting on the background execution.

Comment: @RowlandShaw It is actually communicating with the exchange server and yes I am using await there.